# Magento 2.1.9 - CSS files not being merged

Tags: magento-2.1, merge-css

I'm running Magento 2.1.9 on nginx 1.8.1
In `Stores` - `Configuration` - `Advanced` - `Developer` under CSS Settings
I've selected:

- Merge CSS Files: yes
- Minify CSS Filey: no

Then I'd flush my Magento cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

My shop is in production mode but I still see my CSS files:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="domain.etc..Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/calendar.css" /> 
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="domain.etc..Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="domain.etc..Smartwave/porto/en_US/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="domain.etc..Smartwave/porto/en_US/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="domain.etc..Smartwave/porto/en_US/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
```

19 CSS files in total.
Is it possible to merge them somehow?

Comment: Check value dev/css/merge_css_files = 1 or not in database.

Comment: Yes, I've got that one in my db.

Comment: Then, It is already merged. But, if dev/css/merge_css_files  = 0 then it is still not merged.

Comment: But I can see from the source code, that my css files are not merged .. that's the reason why I asked here ...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the media="all" param. If you remove it, CSS will get merged.